# Git status fatal error: working tree directory

Tags: git, git-branch, git-status

When trying to *git status* I get the following

git status
*fatal: not a git repository: D:/path/path/path/.git/worktrees/horus_app_v100*

the path *worktrees/horus_app_v100* doesn't exist

I recently deleted a worktree named horus_app_v100 and its branch, but it seems that there is something connected, so I can't git status.

There is no worktree called horus_app_v100, cuz I deleted, there is only my main worktree (1 worktree), but git status seems to be trying to reach a directory/worktree that doesn't even exist

Comment: How did you delete the worktree?

Comment: git worktree remove horus_app_v100

Comment: Where did you run this command? Can you run `git status` in the same folder?

Comment: I can't run git status anywhere  

- project - 
              .git
             /folder1 
             /folder2 
             /folder3 

in all these folders git status returns fatal: not a git repo 'path to the deleted worktree'

Comment: Where did you run the command `git worktree remove horus_app_v100`?

Comment: the only thing that worked was creating the worktree 'horus_app_v100 again'.. 

but doing this, slows down a lot all the other commands, like git status

Comment: I ran git worktree remove horus_app_v100 in the root folder, where .git is located

Comment: What happens if you run `git status` in the root folder where the `.git` is located? Do you still see an error?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error and git checkout show files I didn't change, probably from the deleted worktree

Comment: It is like, deleting the worktree has overridden my main worktree, although there is only 1 worktree listed in  ' git worktree list '

Comment: and creating the deleted worktree again, makes everything go back to normal

Comment: Try running `git worktree prune`?

Comment: Tried that.. didn't work : (

Comment: it's like git status is trying to run in a different directory, inside .git  (.git/worktrees/horus_app_v100, which doesn't even exist). Even though I git bashed inside the root folder (which contains the .git)

Comment: Try deleting `.git/worktrees/horus_app_v100` and then `git worktree prune`?

Comment: man.. I made it work here. There was a file (which I don't know how was there, maybe I created trying to fix the problem) called .git [ file, not the folder]. This file was inside one of the child folders of my project. The content of the file was something like gitdir = 'path to the deleted worktree [D:/path/path/path/.git/worktrees/horus_app_v100] . With this file inside, Git didn't even recognized the child folder as part of the Git repository. So I deleted this file (.git) and everything  seems to work now. Thanks for the support, thanks for your time  : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a file (which I don't know how was there, maybe I created trying to fix the problem) called .git [ file, not the folder]. This file was inside one of the child folders of my project. The content of the file was something like gitdir = 'path to the deleted worktree [D:/path/path/path/.git/worktrees/horus_app_v100] . With this file inside, Git didn't even recognized the child folder as part of the Git repository. So I deleted this file (.git) and everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

My basic understanding is that git status checks for a folder called '.git'.
This is where all the git configuration and version control is stored.
Therefore, if there is no '.git' folder then the git command won't have the necessary information see that this is a git repository.

My guess is that '.git' folder got deleted with the horus_app_v100 deletion.

My advice would be, if you have not made any changes, just delete the project and clone it again.

If you have made changes, clone it again and do a comparison between the two projects.

(There must be a better way, but let the Git Gurus help us both out with that)

Comment: The `.git` folder _is the repo_. Without it, it's not a repo

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks I reworded the one part

Comment: Right, I have .git folder in my "main" directory and I tried to git status inside this folder. I think the problem is the worktree I deleted. I created the worktree horus_app_v100 again and everything goes back to normal. But I don't need this worktree or its branch (cuz when I created the worktree, a branch named horus_app_v100 was created)

Comment: @Projetinho Sorry I am having quite some difficulty following what you are trying to achieve. Can you add a problem statement to your question? Something like... "How do I achieve..."

Comment: I'll try to summarize.. I had a worktree which was listed as a branch in 'git branch' ==>   +horus_app_v100, but when trying  'git branch -d horus_app_v100', git complained about saying I had to checkout. That is when I learned that it was a worktree listed as a branch. I ran   'git worktree remove horus_app_v100' and then 'git branch -d horus_app_v100' (which worked, since I deleted the worktree). But after deleting these 2 (worktree and branch), any other command (git status or git diff) shows fatal and git checkout show files I didn't change (probably from the deleted worktree)

Comment: at first, I didn't know what +branch was, so later on I found out it was a worktree, I guess..  If it not clear, if you are available, we can move to chat

Comment: @Reg, I found a solution here. Thanks for the support

Comment: @Projetinho glad to hear. Please add your solution to the question :) It will help someone else in the future